# treating variable using datepicker and timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem and can not solve
on my form the date format is like

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss
```

need to convert the case to register in the database, the column type is timestamp

so I'm using this basic function

```
 function verify($a){               
    return $newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($a));
 }
```

the problem is that when I put more than 13 days the date does not work.

Comment: I put more than 13 days the date does not work explain with eg ..

Comment: Apparently PHP knows it might get cursed if it starts working with 13’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just snowballing something:

```
 function verify($a) {
      $dt = explode(' ',$a);
      $dt1 = explode('/',$dt[0]);
      $dt2 = explode('/',$dt[1]);
      return $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime($dt2[0],$dt2[1],$dt2[2],$dt1[1],$dt1[0],$dt1[2]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function change_to_timestamp($a) {
      $dt = explode(' ',$a);
      $date1 =str_replace('/','-',$dt[0]);
      $date2 = str_replace('/',':',$dt[1]);
      return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime($date1.$date2));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

strtotime() is probably not your best bet for that format, as you are most likely experiencing some ambiguity between the "dd" and the "mm" portion of your dates. You can't do 13 days because it thinks you are trying 13 months.

Perhaps a better function would be DateTime::CreateFromFormat() since you have a known date format as input. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
function verify($a){
        $date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d/m/Y H/i/s", $a);
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date->getTimestamp());
}
```

The concept should work, but the code is not copy/paste tested.

Hope This Helps.

**EDIT:**
Fixed some copy/paste syntax errors.
Didn't mention that this answer requires php >= 5.3.

Also, My first answer was bothering me, mixing the old and new ways of doing dates, so there is this:

```
function verify($a){
        $date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d/m/Y H/i/s", $a);
        return $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Or for something more portable:

```
function ChangeDateFormat($old_format, $new_format, $date_string) {
        $date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat($old_format, $date_string);
        return $date->format($new_format);
}
```

Which could be called like:

```
$newDate = ChangeDateFormat("d/m/Y H/i/s", "Y-m-d H:i:s", $oldDate);
```